# How to find the current position of caret or cursot in ckeditor with type script?

Tags: typescript, ckeditor, position, caret

I use the ckeditor in my angular project.
I want to add an image to that editor everywhere the caret is active.
Actually I add images from a dialoge located outside of ckeditor, so I need keeping the last position of cursor befor the blur event of editor is fired. But I do not know how can get the last position of caret and after selecting the image from that dialog, adding that image to the saved position.
Please explain the process of getting and setting the position of caret in ckeditor.
Thank you in advance